# How to align the ul li perfectly columnwise?

Tags: magento-1.9, submenu

My menu is like this:

[image]

Here is my css code:

```
 .nav-primary {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -85px;
}
.nav-primary li.level0, .nav-primary a.level0 {
    display: inline-block;
}
.nav-primary li {
    position: relative;
}
.nav-primary li.level0 > a {
    color: #70583a;
    margin-top: -5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-family: trebuchet MS;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.nav-primary a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.nav-primary li.level0 ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.nav-primary li.level1 {
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-right: 1px solid #eae4da;
}
.nav-primary li.level0 li.parent > a {
    position: relative;
}
.nav-primary li.level1 ul {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.nav-primary li.level0 ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
}
.nav-primary li.level0 li.parent > a {
    position: relative;
}
.nav-primary .menu-active > ul.level0 {
    width: 655px;
    max-width: 740px;
}
.nav-primary .menu-active > ul.level0, .nav-primary li.level0 li.sub-menu-active > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

I want the `submenu8` to be exactly aligned under `submenu1`.I need that kind of alignment. How to do that Please help.

Comment: try to set, `max-width` on `<ul>`. Or post a website link

Comment: yea i have set max-width:74px. I just want the last element to be displayed from the starting of the ul and not at the middle.

Comment: please post website link, so I can try CSS my way

Comment: am working in my local machine. I have updated my question. kindly help

Comment: can you show a part of HTML also ?

Comment: Its default topmenu.phtml file

Comment: try to add this `<div style="clear: both !important;float: left !important;height: 1px !important;width: 100% !important;"></div>` before `submenu8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nth-child` for clearing floats, like this:

`.nav-primary li.level1:nth-child(6n+1) { clear: left; }`

You can also use this method for targeting elements after the first row of menu items:

`.nav-primary li.level1:nth-child(n+7) { margin-top: 20px; }`